# Влияет ли на оптимизацию сайта множественное использование vh vw?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, оптимизация, оптимизация-сайтов

У меня есть вёрстка, там я много раз (можно сказать в 90% случаев)задавал значения с помощью `vh` и `vw`.

Ну сверстал таким образом много секций, вижу что компьютер начинает шуметь, захожу в диспетчер задач, смотрю 30% ЦПУ нагрузка от браузера.. Выхожу со сверстанного сайта всё показывает норм, понижается до 3%..

Это я впервые делаю так, до этого подобного никогда не наблюдал.. И теперь возникает вопрос, действительно ли множественное использование `vh` и `vw` так сильно повлияло на производительность сайта??

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылку на пример вёрстки и браузер, в котором происходит проблема — любопытно посмотреть

Comment: @ArtemKorsunov Вот этот [сайт](https://pranastudio.by/)

Answer (score 1):

Единицы vh и vw не влияют на производительность, скорее всего проблема в большем количестве анимаций.
Ещё, что-то постоянно дёргает пересчёт стилей (посмотрите Performance в DevTools), нужно дебажить.

Answer (score 0):

CSS , тем более такой не большой сайт не может так сильно грузить машину. Попробуй отключить весь js и проверить еще раз. Уверен , что проблема в нем. + Надо проверить пк)

Comment: Попробовал в Firefox отключить JavaScript (about:config -> javascript.enabled). Нагрузка на процессор не снизилась. Потом отключил масштабирование картинки. Нагрузка почти не снизилась. Потом удалил кнопку справа. Нагрузка снизилась примерно на 25%. Может, где-то еще скрытая анимация осталась?